# Assigning variables outside the class constructor for use inside the class?

Tags: php, class

I'm just beginning to work with class constructors. In the script below, I want to pass in the $arg2 value from outside the class.

How do I need to define a variable $someVariable=n, so that it can be set from outside the class constructor from the parent file which includes the file below?

```
class myClassTest
{       
    public $var1;
    public $var2;
    public $var3;

    function __construct($arg1,$arg2=$someVariable){ //MAKE $arg2 dynamically set from outside the class
        $this->var1 = $arg1;
        $this->var2 = $arg2;
        $this->var3 = array();
    }
```

Comment: it's unclear whether you want to assign a value to `$arg2` and then pass that in the constructor, or if you're actually trying to assign a value to `$var2`

Comment: I want to set $someVar=10 outside the class, in the parent script. Then, inside the class constructor I want to define $arg2 = $someVar

Comment: Ah, so you're trying to set the default value of `$arg2` outside the class? You can do it, but it seems counterintuitive; why not simply pass your value directly rather than use it as a default?

Comment: Better to set a class variable in a configuration stage, wherever the including file would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it like this, however it's not recommended

```
$someGlobalVar = "test";
class myClassTest
{       
    public $var1;
    public $var2;
    public $var3;

    function __construct($arg1,$arg2=null){
        if ($arg2 === null){
            global $someGlobalVar;
            $arg2 = $someGlobalVar;
        }
        echo $arg2;
        $this->var1 = $arg1;
        $this->var2 = $arg2;
        $this->var3 = array();
    }
 }
 $class = new myClassTest('something'); //outputs test
```

[working demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/b2e3d.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the default value of argument $arg2 using some 'external' variable. **Default values get (logically) set at 'definition time' of the function**. Thus, these parameters needs to be **literal (constant)** values.

Thus, these are fine declarations:

```
   function makecoffee($type = "cappuccino") { }
   function makecoffee($types = array("cappuccino"), $coffeeMaker = NULL) { }
```

If you want to 'inject' external stuff, you need to do something like this:

```
$someglobalVariable = 'whatever';

class myClassTest
{       
    public $var1;
    public $var2;
    public $var3;

    function __construct($arg1,$arg2=null){ //MAKE $numres dynamic from outside the class

        global $someglobalVariable;

        if ( ! isset( $arg2 ) ) {
           $this->var2 = $someglobalVariable;
        } else {
           $this->var2 = $arg2;
        }
        $this->var1 = $arg1;
        $this->var3 = array();
    }

} // end of class
```

Note, that it is **bad style** to access global variables in PHP (as in any other object-oriented language).